# Recursion - Expressions that evaluate to target

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to understand recursion and solve the problem with

operators = ['','*', "+"]
input : "2224" 
target : 24
output = {"22+2", "2+22", "24"}

Here's the code that I came up with. But it produces invalid output.

```
static List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

static String[] generate_all_expressions(String s, long target) {
    getExpressionsRecur(s, target, 0, null, 0);
    String[] out = new String[output.size()];       
    return output.toArray(out);
}
static void getExpressionsRecur(String s, long target, int currentValue, String currExpression, int currIndex) {

    if (currIndex == s.length()){
        if (currentValue == target) {
            output.add(currExpression);
        }
        return;
    }
    if (currentValue == target) {
        output.add(currExpression);
        return;
    } 
    int currentPart = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(currIndex, currIndex+1));
    if (currIndex == 0) {
        getExpressionsRecur(s, target, currentPart, String.valueOf(currentPart), currIndex+1);
    } else {
        int value = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(currentValue) + String.valueOf(currentPart));
        getExpressionsRecur(s, target, value , currExpression + "" + currentPart,  currIndex+1);
        getExpressionsRecur(s, target, (currentValue * currentPart), currExpression + "*" + currentPart,  currIndex+1);
        getExpressionsRecur(s, target, (currentValue + currentPart), currExpression + "+" + currentPart,  currIndex+1);

    }
}
```

It produces: 
{22+2, 2*2+2*4, 2+2+2*4}

Can someone help me spot the errors?

Comment: Based on the output, I'd say that you haven't implemented operator precedence correctly. If you read `2+2+2*4` as `(2+2+2)*4`, then it is 24, but if `*` has higher precedence than `+`, it should be evaluated as `2+2+(2*4) = 12`.

Comment: Thank you. can you see why it would not print 2+22?

Comment: Your problem is with the call in the "" case. You are calculating value wrongly. 22*2 will become 22*24.But you are saying this new expression has a value of 444 (should be 528) . You can't really use current value. Probably you can restructure your recursion to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

First rethink your recursion since you're not hitting every case.

Write out cases if you need to, maybe start with a 3 digit number since there are less cases; In your code, for example, "24" is never evaluated on it's own.

You are calculating value wrongly for concatenation case. 22*2 will become 22*24.But you are saying this new expression has a value of 444 (should be 528) . You can't really use current value. Probably you can restructure your recursion to make it easier.

You can use this Expression object I threw together in replace of your expression String... call expression.toString() and expression.value() as necessary. But still you'll need changes to your basic recursion structure even after implementing this or similar Expression Object.

```
public class Expression{
    Expression lExpression;
    String lValue;
    Expression rExpression;
    String operator;

    public Expression(String expression) {
        int multIndex = expression.indexOf("*");
        int addIndex = expression.indexOf("+");
        if(multIndex == -1 && addIndex == -1) { 
            this.lExpression = new Expression(Integer.valueOf(expression));
            return;
        }

        if(multIndex != -1 && multIndex < addIndex) {

            this.lExpression = new Expression(expression.substring(0, addIndex));
            this.operator = expression.substring(addIndex, addIndex+1);
            this.rExpression = new Expression(expression.substring(addIndex+1));
        }else {
            if(addIndex == -1) { 
            addIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

        } 
        if(multIndex == -1) { 
            multIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        }
            int opIndex = multIndex < addIndex ? multIndex : addIndex; 
            this.lExpression = new Expression(expression.substring(0, opIndex));
            this.operator = expression.substring(opIndex, opIndex+1);
            this.rExpression = new Expression(expression.substring(opIndex+1));         }



    }
    public Expression(int value) {
        this.lValue = String.valueOf(value);
        this.lExpression = null;
        this.rExpression = null;
        this.operator = null;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return (lExpression!=null ? lExpression : lValue) + (operator !=null ? operator: "") +  (rExpression!=null ? rExpression : "");

    }

    public int value() {
        if(lExpression == null) {
            return Integer.valueOf(lValue);
        }
        if("*".equals(operator)) {
            return lExpression.value() * rExpression.value() ;
        }
        if("+".equals(operator)) {
            return lExpression.value() + rExpression.value();
        }
        return lExpression.value();
    }
```

}